# JPanel CardLayout causes visual glitch between swaps

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, cardlayout

I am trying to create a JPanel with a CardLayout that switches between a menu and a forum when a button is pressed, but I am encountering a visual error where elements of the menu are still displaying when I switch to the forum.

(If relevant, my system specifications are:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015),
2.2 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7,
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,
Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB,
MacOS Monterey 12.6.7)

What follows is a simplified example of my basic implementation. Obviously certain features are not fully implemented in the example.

Main Class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new MainPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MainPanel Class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
    private final Menu menuScreen;
    private final Forum forumScreen;
    public static final String MENU = "1";
    public static final String FORUM = "2";

    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(layout);
        menuScreen = new Menu(this);
        add(menuScreen, MENU);
        forumScreen = new Forum(this);
        add(forumScreen, FORUM);
        layout.show(this, MENU);
    }

    public void navigate (String destination) {
        layout.show(this, destination);
        switch (destination) {
            case MENU -> menuScreen.updateUI();
            case FORUM -> forumScreen.updateUI();
        }
        this.revalidate();
        this.updateUI();
    }
}
```

Menu Class:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Menu extends Screen {

    private final MainPanel panel;

    public Menu(MainPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;

        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(this::delete);
        add(deleteButton);

        Button loadButton = new Button("Load");
        loadButton.addActionListener(this::load);
        add(loadButton);

        Button forumButton = new Button("Forum");
        forumButton.addActionListener(this::toForum);
        add(forumButton);
    }

    private void toForum(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        panel.navigate(MainPanel.FORUM);
    }

    private void load(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    private void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Forum Class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Forum extends Screen {

    private final MainPanel panel;
    private final JSpinner heightField = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,Integer.MAX_VALUE,1));
    private final JSpinner widthField = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));

    public Forum(MainPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;

        add(new Label("Forum", Label.CENTER));

        add(new Label("Height"));
        add(heightField);

        add(new Label("Width"));
        add(widthField);

        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this::exit);
        add(exitButton);
    }

    private void exit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        panel.navigate(MainPanel.MENU);
    }
}
```

Screen Class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Screen extends JPanel {
    public Screen() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }
}
```

Functionally, the code succeeds at switching between the panels, but I've consistently been getting a visual glitch where elements of the last panel display and cover up elements on the new panel. I can still select the elements of the new panel that are covered up, and after I do so, they seem to be switched to the foreground in front of the glitched elements.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3MdX.png)
[Forum with Glitched Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C8HG.png)

Note: this is part of a larger project so the UI seen here may not exactly match the code above. I will note, however, that a similar glitch has been seen throughout the project when using the CardLayout.

I have tried a variety of fixes. I rolled back my java version to java 11, but I still encountered the same problem. I made a loading card to force the ui to update with two switches, but I found that an empty loading card did not solve the problem and a loading card with elements still caused the visual glitch. As seen in the code, I tried a variety of calls that might update the panels such as revalidate, updateUI, and repaint, but nothing I have tried has worked.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Regarding, "*this is part of a larger project ... a similar glitch has been seen throughout the project when using the CardLayout.*" -- If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [mre], code that condenses your code into the smallest program possible, small enough to be allowed to be posted in your question as code-formatted text, that runs for us without modification, that demonstrates your problem for us, and that has no code that is not essential for the above. Please check out the link which explains what this useful tool is and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: If you have questions about how to best create your [mre] after reading the link, please comment back. Again, we should be able to copy and paste the code and then be able to compile and run it.

Comment: One key question that I have to ask is that if you override any component's painting method, and if so, if you call the appropriate super method within your override.

Comment: Also, you don't happen to know what graphics card your computer is using, do you? Is it a NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M?

Comment: The code I have added is a simplified version of my project code--I was just referring to the display as shown in the pictures is from a larger project. If you need me to recreate a basic jframe and main method to run the code above, I can do so, but I didn't want to distract from the code central to the problem.

Comment: The code you have posted is not code that we can run, not code that we can easily use to reproduce the problems ourselves, and that is a problem. I personally don't need anything, but you and your question might benefit from your creating and posting a valid [mre] (again).

Comment: The graphics is just the inbuilt Intel Graphics card

Comment: "*...but I didn't want to distract from the code central to the problem*" -- which is *exactly* why a decent MRE is essential since it forces you to isolate the exact code that causes the problem in a small runnable program.

Comment: as for overriding paint methods, no, I am using the defaults for JPanel

Comment: Are you using AWT components, such as `java.awt.Button`? Sometimes heavy weight components don't play nice with usual Swing lightweight components. But again regardless, MRE.

Comment: The code should be runnable now. Let me know if there are any further issues with this.

Comment: Yes, I am using awt Buttons. using JButtons appears to fix the error. I should note as well, that this would explain why the loading card didn't work either--I was using Labels instead of JLabels. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you, it is runnable, but I had to put them into a single file to make it a MRE. Having done that, I cannot reproduce your problem. Does this code cause the glitch for you? Also, don't mix AWT and Swing components. Change your Buttons to JButtons.

Comment: Yeah, the heavy-weight AWT components can cause problems if mixed with light-weight Swing components. Best to avoid doing this.

Comment: Don't call `updateUI`, it's not doing what you think it's doing, in most case `revalidate` and `repaint` are more the enough

Comment: yeah, I might remove that part since the glitch has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the visual glitch is resolved by switching from awt components (Button and Label) to swing lightweight components (JButton and JLabel). For instance, the menu class is:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Menu extends Screen {

    private final MainPanel panel;

    public Menu(MainPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;

        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(this::delete);
        add(deleteButton);

        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Load");
        loadButton.addActionListener(this::load);
        add(loadButton);

        JButton forumButton = new JButton("Forum");
        forumButton.addActionListener(this::toForum);
        add(forumButton);
    }

    private void toForum(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        panel.navigate(MainPanel.FORUM);
    }

    private void load(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    private void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }
}
```

Credit and thanks to [hovercraft-full-of-eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Comment: If you decide to post your own answer, I will delete this one.